# Win 2008 r2 -- client and server are both behind a NAT

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, rdp

I am new to win2008.

I have a Win2008 R2 server installed and need to know how to get a client system (Win7), using remote desktop, terminal server, or whatever windows 2008 provides, to connect to it (as a user or an admin).

Both the client (Win7) and the server (win2008) are behind a inside a NAT firewall with internal `192.168.x.x` addresses and external `173.64.x.x` Internet addresses. The client and the server are in separate cities. How can I  use the internet from the client (Win7) to connect to the server (Win2008). On both systems, I have "allowed other systems to connect".

I am familiar with tcp/ip, ports......etc.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? Have you opened the ports and setup forwarding for RDP?

Answer (score 5):

> Both the client (Win7) and the server (win2008) are inside a NAT (with 192.168......... addresses). Both have real internet addresses (they are in different cities 173.64.......). How can I use the internet from the client (Win7) to connect to the server (Win2008).

If you have both machines behind a different NAT device, the simplest way you can get this to work is by port-forwarding to 3389/tcp on the Win2008 machine.

Let's assume the topology looks like this:

```
[Win7]------------[FW_A]---------------[FW_B]-------[Win2008]
      LAN_A                                   LAN_B
      192.168.1.x                             192.168.1.x
```

You need to configure port forwarding on `FW_B` to 3389/tcp on Win2008's 192.168.1 address.  Under most circumstances `FW_A` has no explicit configuration required, it will pass this RDP traffic like any other.  Win7 would connect to `FW_B`'s outside 173.64 address on whatever TCP port has been chosen to forward to 3389/tcp on Win2008.

Comment: -1. "The only way" is wrong, He could also possibly etablish a VPN or reorganize the network, so "the only way" is not true. Maybe the most sensible, but not the only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But your suggestion have LAN_A and LAN_B are on the same network. I already have this configuration working fine. The problem is that the second LAN is not local, it is in another city. So, I would think that I have to use the internet to establish the remote connection.  I am right?  Thams, Mike

Comment: @Mike-Dehari, If you are using NAT, it won't matter whether LAN_A and LAN_B are on the same subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The LANs are in different cities. The LANs are Independent of each other. Win7 and win2008 both have NATs and also an IP addresses. Thanks , Mike

Comment: @MikeDehari it doesnt matter whether the LAN subnets are different or the same.  NAT hides these details when you are connecting across the internet

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there a book , an article or a website that covers the details and the how tos. I read the microsoft book and went to their website. Also google the subject, but still can't connect. Thanks, Mike

Comment: This might be a good start: http://www.internet-computer-security.com/Firewall/NAT.html

Comment: @MikeDehari this is more a firewall network configuration topic than something you would find on Microsoft's website. If you are trying to learn the firewall/networking aspects, I would start with a book and maybe work with a consultant if you don't have the resources inhouse to set this up.